# how can I set up a site that loads images dynamically from file and shows them preferably with flask

Tags: ajax, image, flask

** I am a super noob to web/server-side but not to python **

I want to set up a website that goes through a large set of images , reads each one iteratively, and sends it out to be displayed.

The person logging into the website should see a slow video or random images that switch every second ( or down to 1/10 of a second for that matter).

What I have thus far :

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg" id="myImage" />
<script>
setInterval(function() {
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = "http://127.0.0.1:2222/";
 }, 1000);
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

flask side:

```
images_paths_list = glob.glob(r"c:\path\to\images\*.png")
@app.route('/')
def send_image():
     single_image_path = random.choice(images_paths_list)
     print(single_image_path)
     response = send_file(single_image_path, mimetype='image/png')
     return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=2222)
```

This successfully sends an image.

**The issue**:

Only the first image is sent. It seems that this is because in the html side the url is the same - and js tries to optimize by not reloading if the url is the same. I tested it and the theory holds.

I probably need some ajax in the mix to invoke the flask to send a new image and to reset the existing image?

Any help on even parts of the problem would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by specifying no cache.

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="800">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
    var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = context.getContext("2d");

    var drawing = new Image();
    drawing.src = "http://127.0.0.1:2222/send_img"; 

    function loaded() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        context.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
   }

    drawing.onload = loaded

    setInterval(function () {
        drawing.src = "http://127.0.0.1:2222/send_img";
    }, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

python:

```
import glob
import os
import random

import cv2
from flask import send_file
from itertools import cycle

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.cache_control.max_age = 0
    response.cache_control.public = True
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return response

images_list = glob.glob("/path/to/images/*.png")
grid_images = cycle(images_list)
print(images_list)


@app.route('/send_img')
def send_img():
    img = next(grid_images)
    print(img)
    response = send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
    return response


@app.route('/')
def get_front_end():
    return open(FILE_PATH + '/android_image_server_side.html', mode="r").read()

app.run(port=2222)
```